# Why does sed substitution command with the flag p print the modified output twice?

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

My a.txt has contains the following:

```
apple
123
pear
1234
```

If I run this command below,

```
sed 's/123/AAA/p' a.txt
```

I thought I would get

```
apple
123
AAA
pear
1234
AAA4
```

because sed automatically prints each line by default. And I was expecting my modified output after that which has been modified in pattern space.
But my actual output prints the substitution twice:

```
apple
AAA
AAA
pear
AAA4
AAA4
```

Why is that?

Comment: Because printing occurs at the end of the process cycle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sed 's/123/AAA/p' a.txt
```

This expression contains two commands

- `s/123/AAA/` means, find lines with `123` and replace `123` with `AAA` in its first instance on those lines where it occurs. By default, `sed` prints every line, so, the whole stream is printed with the modifications
- `p` means, print the pattern space. At the point where we call `p`, the pattern space contains the modified lines, so they are printed again.

The combination of `s` and `p` is usually used with `-n`, when we only want to print the lines of the stream that were found by `s` and therefore changed.

The order of commands matters. In your command, If you put `p` first, it will print the unmodified stream, close to what you expected:

```
$ sed 'p;s/123/AAA/' a.txt
apple
apple
123
AAA
pear
pear
1234
AAA4
```

Here when we call `p`, the pattern space is the entire file, because we haven't specified any part of it, and it hasn't been changed. The `s` command also prints the whole file, but also modifies it, so we see the stream twice, modified and unmodified.<sup>1</sup>

So perhaps it helps to think that the commands in a `sed` expression are applied cumulatively from left to right, and as steeldriver said, the output you get in this case is due to `p` being applied at the end of the cycle, after `s` has been used to select and modify part of the file.

---

<sup>1</sup> Originally, the command I had here was `sed 'ps/123/AAA/' a.txt`. As helpfully pointed out in [a comment by mxmlnkn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878497/why-does-sed-substitution-command-with-the-flag-p-print-the-modified-output-twic/878544#comment1939908_878544), this command does not work in GNU `sed`. I had been using BusyBox `sed` (in Termux on Android), and didn't test the command properly in GNU `sed` on Ubuntu (bad!). But it's interesting to know that GNU `sed` differs from others in requiring a semicolon here.

Comment: `sed 'ps/123/AAA/' a.txt` does not work for me. It gives `sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command`. Note that `sed -n 'p; s/123/AAA/p' a.txt` yields exactly the output expected in the question.

Comment: @mxmlnkn thanks so much for this comment! With [help from Eliah Kagan in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51289260#51289260) I realised how I had ended up with that wrong command in my answer. Regarding the command you gave last, I feel like it would be beyond the reasoning of my answer to include it, and I don't want to modify my answer too much since it has already been upvoted, but maybe the question would benefit from another answer, if you care to post one? (Otherwise, if you think I should change my answer further, feel free to suggest or edit)

Comment: GNU sed does not actually require a semicolon; it also [allows a newline](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Multiple-commands-syntax.html). ;) However, AFAICT a semicolon is the only thing that's [mandated by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) and thus guaranteed to work in all compliant implementations.